# How to import products with variations in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to import products from an XML with variations.
The import for the products works so far but it doesn't create the variations.

Here is my code (simplified):

```php
    /**
     * @return int
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // avoid reaching memory limit
        ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

        // set tax id
        $this->setTaxId();
        if (empty($this->taxId)) {
            return 1;
        }

        // read products from import xml file
        $importProducts = $this->loadProducts();
        $csvBatch = array_chunk($importProducts, self::BATCH);
        $productNumbers = [];

        foreach ($csvBatch as $products) {
            $productNumbers[] = $this->processImportProducts($products, false);
        }

        $this->deleteProducts(array_merge(...$productNumbers));

        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * @param $productsData
     * @param $progressBar
     * @return array
     */
    private function processImportProducts($productsData, $progressBar)
    {
        $products = [];
        $productNumbers = [];

        foreach ($productsData as $product) {
            $products[$product['SKU']['@cdata']] = $this->importProducts($product, $progressBar);
            $productNumbers[] = $product['SKU']['@cdata'];
        }


        // upsert product
        try {
            $this->cleanProductProperties($products, $this->context);
            $this->productRepository->upsert(array_values($products), $this->context);
        } catch (WriteException $exception) {
            $this->logger->info(' ');
            $this->logger->info('<error>Products could not be imported. Message: '. $exception->getMessage() .'</error>');
        }
        unset($products);

        return $productNumbers;
    }

    /**
     * @param $product
     * @param $progressBar
     * @return array
     */
    private function importProducts($product, $progressBar)
    {
         ...

         $productData = [
            'id' => $productId,
            'productNumber' => $productNumber,
            'price' => [
                [
                    'currencyId' => Defaults::CURRENCY,
                    'net' => !empty($product['net']) ? $product['net'] : 0,
                    'gross' => !empty($product['net']) ? $product['net'] : 0,
                    'linked' => true
                ]
            ],
            'stock' => 99999,
            'unit' => [
                'id' => '3fff95a8077b4f5ba3d1d2a41cb53fab'
            ],
            'unitId' => '3fff95a8077b4f5ba3d1d2a41cb53fab',
            'taxId' => $this->taxId,
            'name' => $productNames,
            'description' => $productDescriptions
        ];

        if(isset($product['Variations'])) {
            $variationIds = $product['Variations']['@cdata'] ?? '';
            $productData['variation'] = [$this->getProductVariationIds($variationIds)];
        }

        return $productData;
    }

    /**
     * Get product variation ids
     *
     * @param string $productVariations
     * @return string
     */
    private function getProductVariationIds($productVariations)
    {
        $productVariationIds = explode(',', $productVariations);
        // get product variationIds in form of a string list
        $ids = $this->productRepository->search(
            (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsAnyFilter('productNumber', $productVariationIds)),
            $this->context
        )->getIds();

        return implode(',', $ids);
    }
```

It loads correctly the ids but nothing happen. Also no error.

Anyone an idea how to import variations as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `variation` field is not meant to be persisted or to create variants of a product. [It has the `Runtime` flag](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Content/Product/ProductDefinition.php#L157), meaning it's not an actual database column but processed during runtime.

You have to create/update variants just like you create the parent product. Additionally you have to set the `parentId` and the `options`. The latter being associations to [`property_group_option`, which you'll have to create first](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/c2NoOjE0MzUxMzIw-property-group-option).

So in addition to your existing payload when creating parent products, you'll have to add this data to the variants:

```php
$productData = [
    // ...
    'parentId' => '...',
    'options' => [
        ['id' => '...'],
        ['id' => '...'],
        ['id' => '...'],
        // ...
    ],
];
```

Finally you'll have to create the `product_configurator_setting` records. That's one record for each option used across **all** variants. Also the `productId` for the records has to be the one of the parent product.

```php
$repository = $this->container->get('product_configurator_setting.repository');

$configuratorSettings = [];
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $configuratorSetting = [
        'optionId' => $option['id'],
        'productId' => $parentId,
    ];

    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('productId', $parentId));
    $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('optionId', $option['id']));

    $id = $repository->searchIds($criteria, $context)->firstId();

    // if the configurator setting already exists, update or skip
    if ($id) {
        $configuratorSetting['id'] = $id;
        // continue;
    }

    $configuratorSettings[] = $configuratorSetting;
}

$repository->upsert($configuratorSettings, $context);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addition to make things easier. When creating a product with variants you can just update the configuratorSettings of the parent/father/main-product (whatever you call it).
Then Shopware6 will go and create the variant products automatically. Also the uuids of the children are created automatically. So if need to keep track of these you have to query them after the creation process.
But for a fast creation this might be much faster, if you have a lot of variants the only "variation" are the options. So no special images or texts.